# How to solve and graph a linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say you are given a question that is $3x+7y=-37$ and you are told to graph and solve this equation. How do you solve this equation to get the points on the graph.

Comment: $3x+7y=-37$ is a line you need two point of it to make its graph. forexample put $x=0$ then $7y=-37$ so $y=\frac{-37}{7}$ 

and for $x=1$, $3(1)+7y=-37\Rightarrow 7y=-40\Rightarrow y=\frac{-40}{7}$

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algebra/ac1/eqlines2.htm

Comment: @RaziehNoori Didn't find the link very helpful do you have any other links that could explain this.

Comment: dear, i that link it teaches how have graph of a line. if you need this still, let me know i will write it and upload its image

Answer (score 1):

A linear equation in $x$ and $y$ is simply the equation of a stright line.

Put your equation in the form: 
$$
y=-\dfrac{3}{7}x-\dfrac{37}{7}
$$
and, using two values for $x$ find the values of $y$, so you have the coordinates of two points and the line passing between these points is the graph.

---

Usually I use $x=0$ to find the point where the line intersect the $y$ axis, in this case we have:
$$
x=0 \Rightarrow y= -\dfrac{37}{7}
$$
so a point is $(0,-\dfrac{37}{7})$
Now we can chose any other valu for $x$, e.g. $x=-7$ and find
$$
y=3-\dfrac{37}{7}=-\dfrac{16}{7}
$$
and we have the other point $(-7,-\dfrac{16}{7})$, and the line passing through these two points is the graph. This means that all values of the coordinates $(x,y)$ of points of this line are solution of the given equation.

Comment: So you just solve by make 2 fractions and subtracting 3-37 and 7-7 to be 34 over 0.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's usefull :)